# Is it possible to maintain tomcat configuration in server.xml, when deploying web apps via Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gridgain

When webapps are deployed via Eclipse to Tomcat, $catalina_home/conf/server.xml is getting overwritten by Eclipse.  This means, whatever changes I make to server.xml prior to app deployment is overwritten by Eclipse.

My application uses GridGain and hence I need to add the following line to server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.gridgain.grid.loaders.tomcat.GridTomcatLoader" configurationFile="config/default-spring.xml"/>
```

Since Eclipse overwrites server.xml every time I deploy a new version of the app, I need to instruct Eclipse to insert the above line (this is applicable for all tomcat event listeners) as well during deployment.  Is this possible?  If not is there a workaround for GridGain based applications to be deployed via Eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse uses `${workspace}/Servers/${server-name}/server.xml` for its configuration. That directory is created when you setup a new server. It's not overwritten every time you deploy the app but only if you make changes in the server config UI. If you need to add something manually to `server.xml` then do so and set the file to read-only e.g. directly in Eclipse:

- locate the file (see path above)
- right-click
- Properties
- Resource
- enable "Read only"

That way Eclipse will ask/notify you everytime it tries to alter the file and you can allow/disallow that.

Comment: Assuming you are using Eclipse's Web Tools Platform, or something based on it, rather than a standalone Tomcat launcher.

Comment: Right, forgot to mention. No surprise you comment on that ;-)